# How much do max current specs matter on VCC and GND?

Tags: power-supply, current, specifications

I know that each of the output pins on most chips have a specification for the maximum power that can be drawn from that pin.

However, some chips also have a spec for the max. current through VCC and ground, and these specs are less than the sum of all possible output currents for the chip.

So, why do those total current specs exist, and is it okay to exceed them?  (I wouldn't want to exceed the current spec. on a pin that actually does something, but for something passive like VCC, it sounds safe enough...)

Comment: Specific chip part number would help here. Also VCC is not "passive".

Comment: Datasheet: http://www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/74HC_HCT595.pdf

Comment: There's no issue/error in that datasheet. The (max) 70mA through the VCC/GND pins at (max) 7V supply would dissipate 490mW... which is very close to the 500mW limit of most packagings for that IC (see table 4).

Comment: @RespawnedFluff, does that mean that you could run 100mA at 5V?

Comment: It's not guaranteed. If you're lucky, it may work; this is like overclocking. The max power dissipation for the package is a good way to check that those numbers (as stated) make sense. But the max power dissipation is an aggregate figure ignoring that the "weakest link" (like a bonding wire) can break/burn before the power for the whole package is exceed and it starts to smoke. That's why they have these per-pin current limits.

Comment: Have a look at the insides of an IC e.g. http://electronics.macdermid.com/images/cms_images/ff%20wire%20bond.jpg to see what the bonding wire is like. They can of course use different thickness wires internally for various pins.

Comment: Here's another image where you can see that they have used wires of different thicknesses http://www.azom.com/images/Article_Images/ImageForArticle_8528(2).jpg So it's not just a theoretical possibility. And wires are of course not only parts that can have their current limit (ampacity) exceed inside a chip. Junctions etc. also have such limits, but those are harder to illustrate with an image.

Comment: Given the values listed in that datasheet I suspect they use two wires for the power pins and one for the rest. It's not uncommon see http://i.stack.imgur.com/lLOPz.jpg for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The current for a pin is limited by the strength of the driver for that pin.

The current for the VCC and VDD pins is limited by the size of the bond wire between the pin and the die inside the chip. Exceeding these limits may damage that bond wire.

Answer (score 1):

It is never OK to exceed an 'absolute max' spec on a chip and expect the chip to function normally.  That particular spec exists precisely because it is possible to draw very large currents on the Vcc or Gnd pin while staying within the individual spec for all of the other I/O pins.  The die inside the microcontroller is sort of a circuit board in its own right.  The pins are connected to the die with very thin bond wires.  These wires and the traces on the metal layers of the die itself are very small and can only carry so much current.  If you try to draw too much current, it will cause the voltage on the die to droop.  The direct result of this could be undesired behavior, resets, etc.  The resistance of the bondwire and traces that cause the voltage drop will also produce heat that can cause issues, up to and including damaging the bondwire and/or die.

If you really need to supply that much current, you should use external power transistors and/or port multipliers to take the load off of the microcontroller I/O pins and internal power distribution network.

Answer (score 0):

If the data sheet lists these values in the Absolute Maximums section, it categorically means that if you go outside of the specified ranges the IC is NEVER GUARANTEED to meet its design spec ever again.  If its important that your circuit works reliably, you don't do this.

Answer (score 0):

The leads, bonding wires, and traces on the IC have a maximum ampacity. If this is violated then the chip could suffer irreversible damage due to debonding or vaporization.